# How to compare the date in firebase with the current date using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, datetime, google-cloud-firestore

Please am new to using Laravel and firebase. Please how do I compare the date inside my firebase with the current date, I want to check if the inserted date in my firebase is greater than or equal to the current date. Below is what I have done but it is not working, please any help will be appreciated.

Note: this is my date format in firebase "2023-08-31"

I'm running a cron job that check the current date of any inserted user, once the cron jobs check the date if the current date is greater then the inserted date the user will be debited. My cron job is working perfectly but it is not debiting the user because of the date I initiated.

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Carbon\Carbon;


use DateTime;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class DailyChargez extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'DailyChargeUserz:cron';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        
        \Log::info("Cron is working fine daily!");
        
        


$mydate = Carbon::now();


$daily = app('firebase.firestore')->database()->collection('Payment');
$query1 = $daily->where('paymentType', '==', 'Recurring Payment')
->where('active', '=', true)
->where('frequence', '==', 'Daily')
->where('deductionDate', '<=', $mydate)


$documents = $query1->documents();
foreach ($documents as $document) {
    if ($document->exists()) {
       
    $postDataz = [
     'authorization_code' => $document->data()['authenticate'],
    'email' =>  $document->data()['email'],
    'amount' => $document->data()['amountToCharge'] * 100,
      
      "metadata" => [
            "custom_fields" => [
         [
                "value" => $document->data()['paymentMethod'],
                "display_name" => "Payment Method", 
               "variable_name" => "payment method", 
         ], 
        [
             "value" => $document->data()['packageName'],
                "display_name" => "Package Name", 
               "variable_name" => "package name", 
            ],
             
         
         
      ]
      ]
     
     
      ];
      
    }
    
    

      
        $url = "https://api.paystack.co/transaction/charge_authorization";
  $fields_stringz = http_build_query($postDataz);
  //open connection
  $ch = curl_init();
  
  //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_stringz);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Authorization: Bearer *******",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
  ));
  
  
  //So that curl_exec returns the contents of the cURL; rather than echoing it
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
  

  $result = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
     $info = json_decode($result);
     
  
       
    
}    
    }
}
```

Comment: *"but it is not working"* - What, **specifically**, isn't working? Do you get any errors? What is happening vs what do you expect to happen? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77025527/edit) and include more details.

Comment: Sorry about that, I just updated it.

Comment: That's a better description, but there's no code to support what you're expecting... Your `handle()` method doesn't do anything with `$query1`, so when you say *"it is not debiting the user because of the date I initiated."*, I have to respond with "why would it? There's no code beyond `$query1 = ...`... Also, double-check the `where()` method of Laravel's Collection class: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-where. `where()` filters the collection, but it doesn't return `true` or `false`, it returns another Collection. You need to do something with that...

Comment: @TimLewis I'm running a recurring payment using a cron job that checks firebase to see if any users date is backward and not in future that is, if Mr. A date is 2023-08-31 the system will check the current date and debit the user because the current date is greater than Mr. A date

Comment: Also, do some testing and debugging; `'2023-08-31' <= Carbon::now()` (`Carbon::now()` being `'2023-09-01 15:32:00'`, and you could use `Carbon::today()` instead)  is `true`, since `Carbon` uses string comparison, and `YYYY-MM-DD` is a format that can be easily compared. But again, you're not doing anything with `$query1`, unless you omitted additional code.

Comment: i have added my full code, you can check it out

Comment: Yeah, so that's _a lot_ more code... Are you sure the issue is with `->where('deductionDate', '<=', $mydate)`?

Comment: Please dont be offended, am using this format in my firesbase "Y-m-d" so how do i go about your option please

Comment: Not offended, but I don't think your issue is with that line of code. Why do you think it is? To me, this looks like an issue: `where('paymentType', '==',`, then `->where('active', '='`; why the `==` vs `=`? Correct syntax would be `=` for that.

Comment: yes, the error is from ->where('deductionDate', '<=', $mydate), if i remove it, it will execute but if i add ->where('deductionDate', '<=', $mydate) it wont execute

Comment: Ok, so once again, you'll need to do some debugging. If `deductionDate` is `'2023-08-31'`, then `->where('deductionDate', '<=', Carbon::now())` should evaluate to `true`. If it isn't, then you'll need to debug _why_.  An easy first step is `dd($query1);` with and without that `->where()` clause, and see what results you get.

Comment: how do i go about that please, can you help write it please dont be offended please

Comment: Again, not offended (why do you keep thinking that I am ), but no, I can't, because I don't have access to your code... This is why I'm saying _you_ need to debug your code. If you don't know how to debug, I can't really teach you in a 500 character message window here, sorry...

Comment: Please i would want to know that please .

Comment: when i used the method you sent above, this was the error i got ...  "message": "The query requires an index. You can create it here: https:\/\/console.firebase.google.com\

Answer (score 0):

Firestore stores dates as Timestamps, and you are comparing those to a Carbon date object which might not be working. To convert the Carbon date to a Firestore Timestamp you could do this:

```
// Convert Carbon date to Firestore Timestamp
$mydate = new \Google\Cloud\Core\Timestamp(Carbon::now());

$daily = app('firebase.firestore')->database()->collection('Payment');
$query1 = $daily->where('paymentType', '==', 'Recurring Payment')
    ->where('active', '=', true)
    ->where('frequence', '==', 'Daily')
    ->where('deductionDate', '<=', $mydate);

// ... rest of your code
```

Have the google/cloud-firestore package installed to use Firestore Timestamps. Include the following into your script above `use Carbon\Carbon`

```
use Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient;
```

Comment: please @paul am new to using this, and am confused when u said i should have gogle/cloud-firestore package installed to use firestore timestamp. Currently, in my website, i can run CRUD so since i can run CRUD that means i have google/cloud-firestore package installed right?  because am kind of confused when you said i should have google/cloud-firestore package installed?

Comment: Meanwhile, i have done as you stated above but yet it is not working, please dont be offended is there anything am missing please or better still can you use my full code above to show me the way it's meant to be please . i will appreciate it

Comment: And please i just added this to my code above and i dont know if it is installed or not please "use Carbon\Carbon" and am running this my code inside my command that is App/Console/Command/ so can you put me through please

Comment: "*it is not working*" - What, specifically, isn't working? Do you get any errors? (& suggest use of Google to get install instructions)

Comment: Re install. You may have this done already. See https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cloud-firestore.html  it is impossible in these tiny comments to provide tuition. (I'm not offended nor intend to cause offence.)

Comment: I tested my code by creating a new controller and i could display current time but when I insert such inside my code above it won't execute but if i remove the date it will execute

Comment: my firebase is working fine but what am not getting right is how to compare the current date from the date inside my firebase with the current date

Comment: i got this error "App\Console\Commands\Google\Cloud\Core\Timestamp" not found"

Comment: Because the needed package isn't installed.

Comment: Please note I literally cannot help with this further and it isn't guaranteed that my suggestion will solve your issue.

Comment: Dont be offended please @paul am just looking for solution to my code please, if i have gotten the help i will be the most happiest person on earth, i have been trying my best to get this solve please. Please how can i install the package, what command should i use to get this "App\Console\Commands\Google\Cloud\Core\Timestamp" installed

Comment: I have added to my answer. If that does not fix the problem I'm afraid **I really do not know how to jelp further**